# String replaceAll with specific numeric values with a double

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a requirement to replace a given string expression with numbers.

E.g: A string `1+3+5` needs to replaced with following values

```
1 = 270.5
3 = 377.5
5 = 377.5
```

But it not working as expected.

#### Actual Result

```
270.5+377.377.5+377.5
```

#### Expected Result

```
270.5+377.5+377.5
```

***Note:*** *I used word boundary `\b`*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You obviously replace them one after another and the `.5+` after replacing 3 is also replaced by the replacement for 5. `\b` doesn't fit your purpose

Comment: Yes the word boundary doesn't seem to fit here. Kindly suggest appropriate solution which replaces the whole numeric value instead of numeric character..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a hash map to define the replacements, and replace using `Matcher#appendReplacement` with a very simple `\d+` regex (since your input contains int values only):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "1+3+5";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("1", "270.5");
        map.put("3", "377.5");
        map.put("5", "377.5");
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            String value = map.get(m.group());
            if (value != null) {
                m.appendReplacement(result, value);
            } else {
                m.appendReplacement(result, m.group());
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(result);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: [Here is an online demo link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNkdzUzg1d1F4VEE).

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression you should check if a number is preceded by a dot or by another number, and in this case not replace it. This will do it:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([^\.0-9]|^)1", "$1270.5");
str = str.replaceAll("([^\.0-9]|^)3", "$1377.5");
str = str.replaceAll("([^\.0-9]|^)5", "$1377.5");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change order of replacements:

```
String s = "1+3+5";
String r = s.replaceFirst("\\b5\\b", "377.5").replaceFirst("\\b3\\b", "377.5").
             replaceFirst("\\b1\\b", "270.5");

System.out.printf("%s%n", r);
//=> 270.5+377.5+377.5
```

Another option is to use a negative lookbehind to assert we don't have `DOT` as preceding character:

```
String r = s.replaceFirst("(?<!\\.)\\b1\\b", "270.5").
             replaceFirst("(?<!\\.)\\b3\\b", "377.5").
             replaceFirst("(?<!\\.)\\b5\\b", "377.5");

//=> 270.5+377.5+377.5
```

Comment: The lookbehinds by themselves won't help because the digits may be part of a float value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the regular expression you are using there. If you are simply specifying the numbers:

```
str = str.replaceAll("1", "270.5");
str = str.replaceAll("3", "377.5");
str = str.replaceAll("5", "377.5");
```

Then the third call will also replace the digit "5" from the decimal number of the previous call: 270.**5** and 377.**5**

There are plenty of regular expressions you can use here. An example is:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^1", "270.5");
str = str.replaceAll("\\+3\\+", "+377.5+");
str = str.replaceAll("\\+5$", "+377.5");
```

The first call will replace the "1" that is in the beginning of the string;
The second call will replace the "3" that is in the middle of two "+" signs;
The third call will replace the "5" that is in the end of the string.

You could also use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`, since each call will only replace 1 occurrence.